# Cancelar eventos de teclas en JavaFx

Tags: javafx

tengo una **aplicación JavaFx** cuya ventana principal tiene varios botones, le he asignado acciones a las teclas `ENTER` y `ESCAPE` con un código como este:

```
scene.setOnKeyReleased((KeyEvent keyEvent) -> {
    System.out.println(" -> " + keyEvent.getCode().toString( )); // trace

    if(keyEvent.getCode() == ENTER) {
        // some action here
    }
    if(keyEvent.getCode() == ESCAPE) {
        // some action here
    }
});
```

Las importaciones necesarias son:

```
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import static javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.ENTER;
import static javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.ESCAPE;
```

He observado (en Windows) que si se pulsa la "barra espaciadora" se van pulsando las teclas del programa de forma sucesiva, quisiera evitar esto, es decir **dejar la pulsación de la tecla espaciadora sin efecto**.

***Nota:*** En el código de ejemplo añadí una línea para trazar la tecla pulsada, sin embargo la pulsación de la barra espaciadora no es capturada.

> Editado: **SOLUCIÓN**

Partiendo de la respuesta de [Gorjesys](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/196887/20709) que me permite detectar la tecla (barra espaciadora). Se marca el evento como consumido para evitar el comportamiento implementado por defecto. Así el código anterior quedaría:

```
// importaciones
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import static javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.ENTER;
import static javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.ESCAPE;
import static javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.SPACE;

// ...

scene.setOnKeyReleased((KeyEvent keyEvent) -> {
    System.out.println(" -> " + keyEvent.getCode().toString( )); // trace

    if(keyEvent.getCode() == ENTER) {
        // some action here
    }
});
scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (KeyEvent keyEvent) -> {
    if (keyEvent.getCode() == ESCAPE) {
        // some action here
    }
    if (keyEvent.getCode() == SPACE) {
        keyEvent.consume();
        // NOTE: Marks this Event as consumed to avoid the
        // default behaviour
    }
});
```

Nota: he movido la detección de la tecla ESCAPE porque algunas veces no es detectada por el método que usaba ([ver pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/196933)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso para detectar la barra espaciadora debes usar un [**Event Filter**](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/filters.htm)

```
import static javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.SPACE;
...
...

    scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {

                           if (keyEvent.getCode() == SPACE) {
                              System.out.println("Tecla SPACE!");
                            }

            }
        });
```

En el caso que requieras consumir este evento simplemente usa el método [**InputEvent.consume()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#consume()) :

```
                       if (keyEvent.getCode() == SPACE) {
                          System.out.println("Tecla SPACE!");

                              keyEvent.consume();


                        }
```

Comment: Saludos. Tu solución permite detectar la pulsación de la barra espaciadora y otras teclas, lo que solventa otro problema que me surgió: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/196933
Pero aun no consigo anular la acción que desencadena por defecto la tecla de espacio.

Comment: Vale, lo tengo, hay que marcar el evento como consumido con `keyEvent.consume();` añadire una respuesta completa